# Help needed with Wine errors

Tags: 20.04, wine

I've followed [this](https://linuxhint.com/install_wine_-ubuntu_20-24/) guide.

> sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

> sudo apt update

> sudo apt install wine64 wine32

When I run

> wine –version

I get this:

```
wine: created the configuration directory '/home/arno/.wine'
0012:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
0012:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
0012:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
0012:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
0012:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
0014:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
0014:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
0014:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
0014:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
0014:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
Could not find Wine Gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
Could not find Wine Gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
wine: configuration in L"/home/arno/.wine" has been updated.
0009:err:module:__wine_process_init L"C:\\windows\\system32\\\2013version.exe" not found
```

Comment: Could you let us know which flavour and version of Ubuntu you’re using?

Comment: It's 20.04.1 vanilla Ubuntu.